# Jquery HTML unescape

Tags: jquery, html

I am just trying to replace html brackets with their ascii equivalent. Particularly `<` for `&lt;` and `>` for  `&gt;` for code inside a pre tag.

There must be a very simple script to do this but I can`t find it.

Something along the lines of the code below except something that works.

```
$('.code').each(function() {
var $this = $(this);
var t = $this.html();
$this.html(t.replace('/</g','&lt;').replace('/>/g','&gt;'));
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: At least one of those is a reserved character in regex; try escaping them with a single ' \ ' character

Comment: Remove the quotes from the regular expressions, but you should really handle this server-side..

Comment: You should never find < or > in the html.  If there are any, they will be rendered as a tag of some kind.  Could you enlighten us as to how you are getting < and > in your HTML?  And if it's not too much trouble, could you throw together an example as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do validation/replacing of `<` and `>` server-side using PHP etc. as people can easily disable JavaScript and evade validation that is client-side. Client-side validation is like saying for a stranger to look after your wallet. Sometimes the stranger will be a nice person and not open it. Sometimes they may be a thief.

Anyway, here is a PHP example:

```
<?php
$raw = $_POST['text'];
$encoded = htmlentities($raw);
// Use the below code if you are inserting the result into a database
$db_encoded = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $encoded);
?>
```

Comment: Ok... Thanks for your help. But this is actually for an internal work wiki, which is built statically using jQuery includes.
I understand and will just make sure we manually enter the values... Or use chilli or something.

Comment: You can use this: [htmlEntities for JavaScript](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/htmlentities-for-javascript/) or use AJAX to retrieve an encoded version from PHP if this isn't what you are looking for.